# pandas: get second row and put it at the end of first row (and automatically create new columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df with multiple row entries and 3 column entries. Now i want to take every second row and append it at the row above. Therefore first I should create the 3 additional columns so that i have 6 column in total. But how does the row appending work?

[image: Problem]

```
baselist=[]
for x in range(len(df)):
    if (x % 2) == 0:
        newdf = df.iloc[x].append(df.iloc[x+1])
        baselist.append(newdf)
```

With this code snippet i could actually get a list of lists (baselist) with the wanted solution, but i cant make a df out of it because of the double column names. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it in the format specified you could do this:

```
df = df.join(df.shift(-1).add_prefix('x_'))
df[1::2] = ''
print(df)

   c1  c2  c3 x_c1 x_c2 x_c3
0  ab  bc  cd   dd   ac   cc
1                           
2  aa  cx  yd   dg   as   cs
3
```

Answer (score 3):

So we can do it with `groupby`

```
pd.DataFrame([y.values.ravel() for x , y in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2)])
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0  ab  bc  cd  dd  ac  cc
1  aa  cx  yd  dg  as  cs
```